# PEAR PHP mailing with name from sender

Tags: php, email, pear, mailer

I am using PEAR's smtp mailer in PHP and it is working great with attachments CC and BB as well as multiple recipients.  My boss needs the sender to say the name of the sender when it is sent to an email.  Our sales reps say that this is a must.  I tried to follow the directions but when I use the code below the email wont send.  Im guessing that all email types within the mailer have to be written in the same format. For example

```
 //GET EMAIL OF USER
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT email, email_pass, fullname FROM u_perinfo WHERE user_id = '$_SESSION[uid]'")
        or die("There was an error when grabbing your email information");
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            if($row[0] != ''){
                $from = "$row[2] <$row[0]>";
            }
            $email_pass = $row[1];
        }

        if(!empty($additional)){
            $email .= ", $additional";
        }

        $recipients = array();
        $headers["Subject"] = $subject;
        $headers["From"] = "$from";
        $headers["To"] = "$email";
        $headers["Cc"] = "$cc";
        $headers["Bcc"] = "$bcc";
```

will produce `John Doe <johndoe@gmail.com>` for the from variable Whereas the the line 
`$from = "$row[2] <$row[0]>;";` turned to `$from = $row[0]` will produce just `johndoe@gmail.com`
When doing it with the later (with just the email) it sends the information and works perfectly.  When trying to incorporate the name it doesn't work at all.  Am I doing something wrong?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**:  this is my mail code that you asked for

```
$crlf = "\n";
        $mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);
        // Setting the body of the email
        $mime->setTXTBody($mailmsg);
          $mime->setHTMLBody($mailmsg);                                           body = $mime->get();
        $headers = $mime->headers($headers);

        //$mailmsg = "Welcome to Addatareference.com! \r\n\r\nBelow is your unique login information.  \r\n\r\n(Please do not share your login information.)$accountinfo";
        /* SMTP server name, port, user/passwd */
        $smtpinfo["host"] = "smtp.emailsrvr.com";
        $smtpinfo["port"] = "25";
        $smtpinfo["auth"] = true;
        $smtpinfo["username"] = "$from";
        $smtpinfo["password"] = "$email_pass";
        /* Create the mail object using the Mail::factory method */
        $mail_object =& Mail::factory("smtp", $smtpinfo);
        /* Ok send mail */
        $mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $body);
```

Answer (score 4):

My problem was, that the name should be quoted as the following:

```
$from = '"Mywebsite.com" <noreply@mywebsite.com>';
```

**if NAME contains ()<>@,;\:". the string should be quoted**

Hope it helps someone ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should Use

```
$from = $row[2]." <".$row[0]."> ";
```

instead

```
$from = "$row[2] <$row[0]>;";
```

Also It can be problem with double semicolon. Use only one semicolon at the end.

Comment: @Dom if my answer exactly what you want then please dont forget to accept it. Thank You

Comment: yeah semicolon was a typo but your suggestion didnt work , do you think that its because all the emails are supposed to be in the same format? ie like in recipients array

Comment: The format you are using is right actualy. ie Joe <jow@gmail.com>. Can you post your mail() code.

Comment: This worked for me EXCEPT I had to remove the trailing space after the close carrot

Answer (score 1):

Add another header:

```
$fullName = $row[2];
$headers["X-Sender"] = "<$fullName>";
```

Comment: This did not work.  Was it a guess or did you write something wrong?